# Enable/ Disable a button by creating custom directive in angular 6

Tags: angular, html, angular6, angular2-directives

Need to enable/disable multiple buttons dynamically on multiple HTML pages on the basis of a conditions i.e. Active = true then enable button and if Active = false then disable the button. How to create and apply custom directive.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disable-directive

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

*.ts*

```
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[disableControl]'
})
export class DisableControlDirective {

  @Input() set disableControl( condition : boolean ) {
    const action = condition ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    this.ngControl.control[action]();
  }

  constructor( private ngControl : NgControl ) {
  }

}
```

*html:*

```
<button [disableControl]="condition">Button 1</button>
<button [disableControl]="condition">Button 2</button>
<button [disableControl]="condition">Button 3</button>
```

`condition` would be a boolean in your component that would disable/enable control when necessary.

Source: https://netbasal.com/disabling-form-controls-when-working-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-549dd7b42110

Comment: your exmaple is working for all controls but Rajesh want disable multiple buttons.. you code may be something like that...

Comment: `
<button  [disableControl]="condition">Disable</button>
<button ([disableControl]="condition">Enable</button>`